# Magento redirect after logout

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

how can I redirect the customers after logout to default store view in magento?
In logout I redirect them another store view.

Comment: You need to extend magento's default `AccountController` and override the `logoutAction` with your custom target address. This answer on how to override controllers should give you a good starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980026/override-magento-controller

Comment: I think you should let the `logoutAction` redirect you to `logoutSuccessAction` in order to let magento reinitialize the visitor context (cookies). If you redirects the user directly to a CMS/page for example, you could have problems because magento cookies won't be renewed. Prefer overriding `logoutSuccessAction` than `logoutAction`

Comment: @Bixi What could the difference be? logoutSuccess doesn't do anything from a cookie standpoint that any other page does. It would be like a user coming to a homepage for the first time. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @benmarks Yep sorry, the problem occurs only when MagentoEntreprise FullPageCache is activated .. When a cms/page is already cached with FPC, there is a bug that makes cookies creation not working because FPC bypass some top-level layers normally used for cookie init

Comment: @Bixi - VERY good to know, but if that's the case, how does this affect home pages which are normally CMS pages? Is there a special case when the default URL is loaded?

Comment: @benmarks Can't remember it completely but my case was a little bit tricky : I had a login form on the home page (that was a cms/page) and when the user submited the form he gets the "Please Enable Cookies" page (we didn't want to deactivate it) because magento didn't refresh cookies ... Anyway, that was a bad day

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately there's not a convenient event hook to manipulate the logout redirect location.

`Mage_Customer_AccountController::logoutAction()` sets a redirect to `::logoutSuccessAction()` on the response object *after* the `customer_logout` event is dispatched, and it's the rendering of the *customer/logout.phtml* template which uses PHP to <s>set</s> echo a javascript param to redirect to the homepage with no OOB possibility to pass an arg for an alternate JS-based redirect.

I think the cleanest solution would be to observe `controller_action_postdispatch_customer_account_logout`, grab the controller object, and overwrite the location header using the response object's `setRedirectWithCookieCheck()` method:

```
public function logoutRedirect($obs)
{
    $obs->getControllerAction()
        ->setRedirectWithCookieCheck(/* your URL param(s) */);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I know it's not elegant, but the easiest method I have found is to copy and modify the template file at `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/logout.phtml` to your own theme directory.

Specifically this line:

```
<p><?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->__('You have logged out and will be redirected to our homepage in 5 seconds.') ?></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    setTimeout(function(){ location.href = '<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>'},5000);
//]]>
</script>
```

By modifying location.href url and even the timeout you can point the user to anywhere just after logout. E.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    setTimeout(function(){ location.href = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*/login') ?>'},500);
//]]>
</script>
```

Again, it's not elegant, but it should be a quick enough redirect that the quick hop on the page will then shove them to another url, in the above example, back to the login screen.

Comment: Care to share the reason for the downvote? It's a legitimate answer to the question.

Comment: `*/*/login` is how Magento keeps track of `module/controller/action` -  see here http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters

Comment: Oh shuckles, sorry. I'm deleting my comment

Comment: very good solution by preventing edting the controlers file thanks a lot @ philwinkle

Answer (score 0):

Write the following method in Your Model > Observer .

```
public function customerLoggedOut(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)    
{    
    $observer->getControllerAction()
    ->setRedirectWithCookieCheck(CustomUrl);    
}
```

Customurl is a url on which you want to redirect after Logged Out.

If you want complete solution for custom url redirection for your ecommerce website after logged In, Logged Out and Registration. Custom Redirection extension can help you. Click on link to get extension. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-redirection.html